# Google Play shows me my app has actions.xml but in fact my app doesn't have actions.xml

Tags: android, google-assistant

I want to publish my new app in Google Play but Google Play shows my app has actions.xml. Last time I didn't add to my project actions.xml and I never have actions.xml in project. Last time I only update library dependencies in my project. How can I know where is this actions.xml or which library added this actions.xml?

This is original message from Google Play

Error: "An active APK or Android App Bundle contains an actions.xml file. In order to continue, accept the Actions on Google Terms of Service." appears in Google Play Console

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution for this odd problem?

Comment: same issue here, any update?

Answer (score 1):

In Google Play Console, selected the app which you want to be published & follow the below steps:

1. Under the "Setup", go to the "Advanced Settings",
2. Click on "Actions on Google" tab,
3. Check the box and accept the terms.

Now you can resume/edit your publishing.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation. After I removed the widgets receiver in the Manifest file, the error message disappeared. It may be related to the Android widgets or something in Manifest.